# How to handle private resolvable address as a iOS peripheral

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I am working on a sample application which has corebluetooth functionality.But how can I handle this private resolvable address on a iOS peripheral device? Could anyone steer me in a right direction so that I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the core bluetooth programming guide from Apple? What code have you tried?

Comment: Yes i tried with corebluetooth api, But the thing is how to handle this scenario as bluetooth address keeps on changing randomly from bluetooth 4.0. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: If your peripheral is an iOS device then you need to use some strategies such as using the device name to try and re-scan for the device if you cannot reconnect by UUID.  It seems that Apple don't intend for iOS devices to act as a peripheral for long-term connections

Comment: Yes Paulw11, i do agree that Apple don't intend for iOS devices to act as peripheral, but this is just only for poc purpose. Thats it.

Comment: Then your only option appears to be to attempt to connect using the last known identifier and if this fails scan for for a likely replacement - e.g. If there is only one device visible with your service then connect to it, or if it has the same advertising name then connect to it.

Comment: Ok i will try with your suggestions and update you on this. But thanks a lot for throwing light on this items.

Answer (score 3):

You can scan for advertising devices and try to match each of the addresses against the IRK of your iOS device. IRKs are exchanged after pairing. The address that matches the IRK (has been generated using that IRK) is the one you should connect to

Comment: Note you will need to pair first in order to obtain the IRK of the iPhone.